# ejericio priority queue Comparable To

Tags: java

Alquien me puede explicar que comportamiento tiene el metodo comparable To al ir metiendo objetos a la cola con prioridad, segun creo si devuelve un negativo el objeto mayor es el que se pasa como parametro. Pero en este ejercicio porque funciona al reves?me saca como mayor el obejto que invoca el metodo pero retorna un menos 1. No entiendo porque del funcionamiento. Si alguien me lo puede explicar ,gracias.

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
  public class TestEx_c_jun14
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
 PriorityQueue<Atomo> q=new PriorityQueue();
int n[]={100,2,10,5,50,20,25,3,1};
for(int i=0; i<n.length; i++)
q.offer(new Atomo(n[i]));
System.out.println(q.peek().toString());
}
}
class Atomo implements Comparable<Atomo>
 {
 int atributo;
 public Atomo(int n) {
 atributo=n;
}
  public int getAtributo() { return atributo; }
  public String toString() { return Integer.toString(atributo); }
  public int compareTo(Atomo e) {
   int c = 0;
   if(e.getAtributo() % getAtributo() == 0)
     c = +1;
   else
     c = -1;
   return c;
 }
}
```

Comment: Y en el metodo compareTo como defino para elegir cual sera el coportamineto, me explico si es -1 para que sea mayor el elemeto que se pasa por argumento y 1 para que sea mayor el elemento que lo invoca. O para hacerlo al reves como se implementa?

Answer (score 0):

Implementar el interfaz *Comparable* es necesario por ejemplo para crear listas ordenadas. Para dar la posibilidad al programador de definir en que caso un objeto se considera menos, igual o más que otro objeto en contexto de secuencia, se define el método

```
public int compareTo(T o){
    // devuelve -1 en el caso que se considera this antes que o
    // devuelve 0 en el caso qque this tiene el mismo orden que o
    // devuelve 1 en el caso que se considera this despues que o
}
```

Una simple implementacion por ejemplo pata Integer sería:

```
public int compareTo(int i){
    return Integer.signum(this - i));
}
```

La implementación en tu caso me parece medio extraño.

```
 if(e.getAtributo() % getAtributo() == 0)
```

este código devuelve **true** si e.getAtributo() dividido por getAtributo() no tiene modulo, significa en el caso que e.getAtributo() es multiple entero de getAtributo().
La implementacion de *compareTo* devuelve 1 en este caso, implicando que **this** sería mayor que e en la secuencia. No tiene mucho sentido así.